# how to create a list of lists out of a single list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to convert a list into a matrix form .I have written the the code below:

```
Grid=[]
count=0
for i in range(N):
    l=[]
    for j in range(N):
        l.append(grid[count])
        count+=1
    Grid.append(l)
```

here, grid is the input list and when I run it, I get below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saikr/PycharmProjects/pythonprog/GlowingBacteria.py", line 80, in <module>
    ret=gb.findSolution(N,C,D,K,grid)
  File "C:/Users/saikr/PycharmProjects/pythonprog/GlowingBacteria.py", line 19, in findSolution
    l.append(grid[count])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

please help me solve this.

Comment: Could you please format your code? :) It is a bit difficult to read, also, what does N mean?

Comment: I meant that I should convert the grid into an N x N matrix.

Comment: Well, you variable "Grid" is an empty list, so of course you will get an IndexError

Comment: what is `grid`? For questions seeking debugging help, you must provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show an example? So for a list like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']`, what would your expected output be? Furthermore, what about a list with a non-square number of elements like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`?

Comment: grid is the input list

Comment: for a grid=[1,2,3,4],I expect the output as Grid=[[1,2],[3,4]] and I only need it for a square no. of elements.@C.Nivs

Comment: your code doesn't raise any error... https://onlinegdb.com/H1wjg-Q6H

Comment: yes, it was not the full program .I got error becoz of some other part of the program@Tomerikoo

Answer (score 1):

You can use another approach for creating matrix using python list.

```
  a = [[x] * m] * n
```

`a` is your desired matrix / multi-dimensional list.

`m` stands for the number of column and `n` stands for the number of row.

and the list `[x]` is the initializer of the list, you can use list comprehension here for initialize these value.

or

```
  N=5
  a = []
  for i in range(N):
      a.append([] * N)
```

do this for simply create an empty matrix of N x N.

Comment: this is not a good idea as all sub-lists will be referencing the same list. Meaning, doing `a[0][0] = y` will make all `a[i][0] = y`. It is more safe to do: `a = [[x for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]`

Comment: agreed with you.

Comment: what is x here?

Comment: the value to initialize the list. like if you entered [0] then the whole list will be initialized with 0

Comment: Doing `[] * N` leaves you with an empty list. So `a` will simply be a list with `N` empty lists. Kinda loses the second `N` in `N x N`